# Why pam_loginuid module fails on writing to /proc/self/loginuid with -EPERM?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I found that application using pam library to authenticate fails on error:

```
Error writing /proc/self/loginuid: Operation not permitted
```

By strace i found that fail is on write to the /proc/self/loginuid file.

Further inspection and adding some debug code to kernel (code below):

```
static ssize_t proc_loginuid_write(struct file * file, const char __user * buf,
                   size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct inode * inode = file_inode(file);
    uid_t loginuid;
    kuid_t kloginuid;
    int rv;

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "proc_loginuid_write\n");

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "a+++ %s\n", current->comm);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "b+++ %s\n", pid_task(proc_pid(inode), PIDTYPE_PID)->comm);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "+++2++ pid = %d\n", current->pid);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "+++3++ pid = %d\n", pid_task(proc_pid(inode), PIDTYPE_PID)->pid);

    rcu_read_lock();
    if (current != pid_task(proc_pid(inode), PIDTYPE_PID)) {
        rcu_read_unlock();
        printk(KERN_ERR "proc_loginuid_write failed by permission!\n");
        return -EPERM;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();


    if (*ppos != 0) {
        /* No partial writes. */
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    rv = kstrtou32_from_user(buf, count, 10, &loginuid);
    if (rv < 0)
        return rv;

    /* is userspace tring to explicitly UNSET the loginuid? */
    if (loginuid == AUDIT_UID_UNSET) {
        kloginuid = INVALID_UID;
    } else {
        kloginuid = make_kuid(file->f_cred->user_ns, loginuid);
        if (!uid_valid(kloginuid))
            return -EINVAL;
    }

    rv = audit_set_loginuid(kloginuid);
    if (rv < 0)
        return rv;
    return count;
}
```

showed in dmesg that:

```
[   30.672242] proc_loginuid_write
[   30.672249] a+++ testapp
[   30.672251] b+++ testapp
[   30.672254] +++2++ pid = 2920
[   30.672257] +++3++ pid = 2451
[   30.672259] proc_loginuid_write failed by permission!
```

Name testapp is intentionally changed name. So it looks like the file /proc/self/loginuid is file created by parent, and it is read by child thread.

I tested same code on kernel 3.14 and 4.9 and on 3.14 kernel it works and on kernel 4.9 it doesn't works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem.

Old **kernel 3.14** has turned off option **CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL** in config. So on there was no file /proc/self/loginuid and pam module simply don't cares when there is no such file.

On newer **kernel 4.9** option is automatically selected by **CONFIG_AUDIT=y**.
So simplest solution is to turn off **CONFIG_AUDIT** option, but why in process of kernel evolution **CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL** became a non controllable option is matter for other question.

Thanks!

Comment: `why in process of kernel evolution CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL became a non controllable option is matter for other question.` - Usually, new  kernel feature, even if its "usefullness" is much more than drawbacks,  is optional and is `disabled` by default. This is because feature implementation may be incorrect. After some time, after the feature is stabilizized a lot, its default may be changed to `enabled`. Looks like configuration of **AUDITSYSCALL** follows exactly this strategy.